# Tag alert e-mail notification timing?

Tags: support, tags, email

I've noticed that my e-mail notifications for questions of a particular tag come later by a few minutes every day. There doesn't seem to be fixed pattern - in fact, it's quite random looking. On average, however, I get notifications later and later. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to get notifications at a particular time - say, in the morning?

---

#### edit:

I wrote [this hackish script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a727902cb2d669623fce) (note: works on OS X only) to create this completely necessary graphical aid:

[image]

Comment: At least you get them, some of us don't get them at all :-)

Comment: The script probably takes 24,1 hours to run.

Comment: My StackOverflow Weekly Newsletter always arrives on Tuesdays but anywhere from  12:30 PM to 7:05 PM CST. Consistently inconsistent.